# Use related entity multiple times in query

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship

I'm trying to get a list of two tables into one list of a generic class I made.

My question is how I could get the fields from the related table without calling firstOrDefault for each field, please see sample code, I need a verly long line for fields Price and Cost, and I have a few more to do...

```
    Dim items As IQueryable(Of ItemMain)


    Return items.Where(Function(i) i.Status > -1).Select(Function(x) New ItemViewBasic() With {.ItemID = x.ItemID,
                                                                      .Name = x.Name,
                                                                      .BarcodeNumber = x.BarcodeNumber,
                                                                      .Price = x.ItemStores.Where(Function(itemStore) itemStore.StoreNo = GlobalValues.StoreID).FirstOrDefault().Price,
                                                                      .Cost = x.ItemStores.Where(Function(itemStore) itemStore.StoreNo = GlobalValues.StoreID).FirstOrDefault().Cost})
```

Comment: Use query syntax which provides `let`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531379.aspx

Comment: Please add this as an answer so I could mark it answered. Thank you.

Comment: You solved the problem on your own, I'd say you get to be the one to add the answer then. Include your resulting code in your answer so people can see how you transformed it exactly.

Comment: okay I did... looks like you don't need some extra points..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting a tip from @Jeroen-Vannevel in the comments about using the let keyword, I figured how to do it. I post it here for future reference..

```
      Return (From i In items Let itemStore = i.ItemStores.Where(Function(its) its.StoreNo = GlobalValues.StoreID And its.Status > -1).FirstOrDefault() Where i.Status > -1
            Select New ItemViewBasic With {.ItemID = i.ItemID,
                                           .Name = i.Name,
                                           .Cost = itemStore.Cost,
                                           .BarcodeNumber = i.BarcodeNumber,
                                           .OnHand = itemStore.OnHand,
                                           .Department = itemStore.DepartmentID,
                                           .Price = itemStore.Price,
                                           .ModalNumber = i.ModalNumber})
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would use (in C#) is first to generate a query for the ItemStore records for the store in question e.g.

```
var itemStores = myDbContext.ItemStores.Where(i => i.StoreNo = GlobalValues.StoreID);
```

Then Join it to the items you already have:

```
return items.Join(itemStores, i => ItemId, is => is.ItemID, (i, is) => new ItemViewBasic {etc });
```

Comment: that's two round trips... I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Not necessarily. The first query will only be executed when it is needed (unless you force early evaluation by adding .ToList() on the end). You may find it optimises to a single SQL query behind the scenes. I'm not sure which way it would go.

Comment: I have a problem with this approach... since I'm using devexpress scaffolding, I don't have direct access to the dbContext at this point. if I make a new instance of the context I get an error saying that I can't relate to contexts...

Comment: Pity. Can't see an elegant way to do it if you don't have the dbContext.  Only thing I can think of is to define an ItemViewBasic2 object that has the StoreID on it as well as what you want. Select all of them regardless of the StoreID and then filter with a subsequent Where clause to get only the ones you want. Finally Select just your ItemViewBasic object. Ugly, but it will still only be one visit to the db and probably result in perfectly optimal SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found how to use the let keyword and that did it for me...